# How add entitlement "com.apple.springboard.launchapplications" for jailbreak iPhone

Tags: ios, background, jailbreak, self-signed, entitlements

I have some problem. I want that my app use next instruction:

```
int SBSLaunchApplicationWithIdentifier(CFStringRef displayIdentifier, Boolean suspended);
```

1. I add SpringboardServices.framework in my project
2. I add URL Schemes for my app

But I can't add entitlement "com.apple.springboard.launchapplications".
I did next: 
1. Created the file entitlement.xml with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">; 
<plist version="1.0"> 
    <dict> 
        <key>com.apple.springboard.launchapplications</key> 
        <true/> 
    </dict> 
</plist>
```

1. Paste entitlement.xml in `Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-efjwoxgwdyixnfassijmwtptxvlj/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/`
2. Paste ldid in `Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-efjwoxgwdyixnfassijmwtptxvlj/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/`

Run command in Terminal: `./ldid -Sentitlement.xml AppName.app/AppName` 
But after this ldid didn't finish and require enter something(didn't write what I must enter only empty row). After that I can exit from ldid process only by pressing ctrl+z

Please, help me

Comment: Where did you get your `ldid` binary from?  I recommend [here](http://code.google.com/p/networkpx/downloads/detail?name=ldid&can=2&q=), or if you've installed iOSOpenDev, then I believe one gets installed in `/opt/iOSOpenDev/bin/`.  Also, it looks like there is an extra semicolon (`;`) in your entitlements.xml file.

Comment: Thank you. I installed iOSOpenDev and all working.
But I have other problems. 
After ./ldid -Sentitlement.xml AppName.app/AppName I did next instruction: ./ldid -e AppName.app/AppName and in console I get double text in entitlement.xml(as print in console entitlement.xml twice)
How I can installed AppName.app to my jailbreak iPhone? 
Thank you

Comment: Please post this `ldid -e` output into your question by using the **edit** link above.  And, please format it to be readable.  If I understand what you're describing, I don't think I've ever seen that (`ldid -e` dumping out the entitlements file, doubled).

Comment: Dump ldid -e AppName.app `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>com.apple.springboard.launchapplications</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>com.apple.springboard.launchapplications</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>`

Comment: Yes, it is my post on link [How add entitlement via ldid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18347180/how-add-entitlement-via-ldid). Please, help me if you not about it's problem

Comment: I know it's your post.  That's why I'm recommending that this question be closed.  We don't need two copies of the question.  In the future, please use the **edit** link, as I already suggested to you, to add more information to your questions.  Please don't keep posting new questions.