# How add entitlement via ldid

Tags: background, jailbreak, ipa, entitlements, springboard

I have some problems. 
I want use in my app next function:

```
int SBSLaunchApplicationWithIdentifier(CFStringRef displayIdentifier, Boolean suspended);
```

- I add SpringboardServices.framework in my project
- I add URL Schemes for my app
- Created the file entitlement.xml with

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
> <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
> <plist version="1.0"> 
> <dict> 
>     <key>com.apple.springboard.launchapplications</key> 
>     <true/> 
> </dict> 
> </plist>
> ```

- Paste entitlement.xml in `Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-efjwoxgwdyixnfassijmwtptxvlj/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/
- Paste ldid in `Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-efjwoxgwdyixnfassijmwtptxvlj/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/`
- Did `./ldid -Sentitlement.xml MyApp.app/MyApp` in console.
  It's good working
  **But I saw some problem:**
- I did ./ldid -e MyApp.app/MyApp and saw next in console(double output entitlement.xml):

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
> <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">; 
> <plist version="1.0"> 
> <dict> 
>     <key>com.apple.springboard.launchapplications</key> 
>     <true/> 
> </dict> 
> </plist>
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
> <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">; 
> <plist version="1.0"> 
> <dict> 
>     <key>com.apple.springboard.launchapplications</key> 
>     <true/> 
> </dict> 
> </plist>
> ```

- I create MyApp.ipa file consist with:

> ```
> ItunesArtwork
> Payload
> |---MyApp.app
> |---Info.plist
> ```

- I installed this ipa file on my jailbreak iPhone via iTools
  MyApp is run but can't do some function. I try authorization via Internet and it's false. But when I installed app without added entitlement an didn't do some instruction with ldid, application working fine.

P.S: i didn't set in true Targets->AppName->Summary->Entitlements property (is it true or false ?)
Please help me

Comment: No, you should not check the entitlements property within Xcode.  You would build in Xcode without code signing, and then *fake codesign* after that with `ldid` and the entitlements file.

Comment: Just look this and you will work:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14871748/how-do-i-change-my-ios-applications-entitlements